Runs as Administrator results in The specified path does not exist
I’m working on a simple application and it needs to run as Administrator.
When I run it from the desktop, it works, but when I run it from a shared drive, I get something like the following error message:

S:\path\app.exe
The specified path does not exist.
Check the path, and then try again.

The S: drive is mapped from a shared folder (\\SERVER\shared).
Obviously it does exist, as I have just right-clicked on it, so I presume that it means something else. What would be the issue here?


Do you have Admin credentials on the S: server? 2. Have you tried running it as Admin from that server, at its keyboard or by Remote Desktop?


This means the credentials you are attempting to run the the application as do not see or cannot access the network path. A mapped drive is only mapped for your logged on user session, and will not be visible to another session, for instance. If you go to the UNC path (rather than the mapped drive), are you able to run the application as Administrator?
